# PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR: relation "index_content_pages_on_parent_id" already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run migration file, when i run it i am getting the error:

```
== 20140507172359 RemoveUnneededAttributesFromNotification: migrated (0.0012s) 

== 20140515121936 SetStatusOnExistingPages: migrating =========================
== 20140515121936 SetStatusOnExistingPages: migrated (0.0000s) ================

== 20140517141938 CreateContentPages: migrating ===============================
-- create_table(:content_pages)
bin/rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled: (StandardError)

PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "index_content_pages_on_parent_id" already exists
/Users/rabeyakhatunmuna/Documents/expertiger-app/db/migrate/20140517141938_create_content_pages.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "index_content_pages_on_parent_id" already exists (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
/Users/rabeyakhatunmuna/Documents/expertiger-app/db/migrate/20140517141938_create_content_pages.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "index_content_pages_on_parent_id" already exists (PG::DuplicateTable)
/Users/rabeyakhatunmuna/Documents/expertiger-app/db/migrate/20140517141938_create_content_pages.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rabeyakhatunmuna@Rabeyas-MacBook-Pro expertiger-app %
```

**db/migrate/20140517141938_create_content_pages.rb**

```
class CreateContentPages < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :content_pages do |t|

      # Note attributes
      t.string :label, default: ''
      t.integer :position, default: 1
      t.boolean :show_in_navigation
      t.string :status, default: 'draft'
      t.string :path
      t.boolean :catch_all

      # Page attributes
      t.string :title
      t.string :layout
      t.string :template
      t.text :abstract
      t.string :image
      t.string :icon
      t.text :meta_keywords
      t.text :meta_description
      t.text :meta_author
      t.text :landing_category
      t.text :landing_tag_list

      t.references :parent
      t.index :parent_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :content_page_regions do |t|
      t.references :page
      t.index :page_id
      t.string :name
      t.text :content
    end

  end
end
```

I want to run the all migration files without any error and fix the error:

tried `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`, still same error:

Comment: Removed a top of irrelevant information, please read [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before asking more questions.

Comment: Your problem most likely comes from the fact that this migration was written 10 years ago and Rails worked a little different back then. You have both `t.references :parent` and `t.index :parent_id`. Try removing the latter and your migration should run. You may also suggest they squash the migrations with this tool, it has been a standard practice in long running Rails project for at least a few years now https://github.com/jalkoby/squasher

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `t.index :parent_id` and `t.index :page_id` lines from your migration file. Because your purpose in creating an index is already served by `t.references`.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if a migration partially ran before (creating the index) but didn't complete for some reason, or if there's a previous migration that created the same index.

Either you can put the index code in a conditional block like this

```
  unless index_exists?(:content_pages, :parent_id)
    add_index(:content_pages, :parent_id)
  end
```

Or you can pass explicit name like this

```
t.index :parent_id, name: 'custom-name'
```